# Fix or Remove album names from multiple songs

Tags: mp3

I've got some 50 odd different album's songs from a friend. But all those songs are tagged with a some same album name. This is incorrect. I need to either fix album name correctly for each song or remove the album name only. But I want to know, how to do the bulk or batch edit of album name for those songs  at one go together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To batch change the ID3 tag on some music, the [id3v2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/id3v2/) utility can be used.  This changes the album name to "Something Else":

```
id3v2 -A "Something Else"  *.mp3
```

On a debian-derived system, id3v2 can be installed via `apt-get install id3v2`.

If by "tagged", you are referring to the file's name, then a different tool can be used.  To remove an album name, say "The White Album", from all mp3 file names in the current directory:

```
rename 's/The White Album//g' *.mp3
```

`rename` is Larry Wall's utility.  It is usually installed as part of perl.  On a *nix machine, it is likely found at /usr/bin/rename

Also, to change the album name to something else is equally easy:

```
rename 's/The White Album/Something Else/g' *.mp3
```

In the above, `s` is for substitute, as in we want to substitute some text for some other text.  The `g` tells it, that if the album name occurs multiple times in the file name, then replace all occurrences.  If you only want to change the first occurrence, omit the `g`.